# Is it possible to edit the search result page of SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to add site pages in the navigation menu of the search results in SharePoint?

[image]

Comment: Create your own search experience with the PnP search web parts.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, customize SharePoint modern search result page is not available.